# Destructuring array elements inside the for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

Let's assume that I have a code structure as below,

```
const fruits = [ `apple`, `banana`, `orange` ];

for ( let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++ ) {

    const res = fruits[ i ];
    console.log ( res ); // apple banana orange
}
```

I want to destructure the

```
const res = fruits[ i ];
```

Is it possible and I can use forEach to achieve the destructuring but I want to achieve the same using the for loop.

Thanks in advance.

PS: using forEach or for..in it can be done but I want to get same destructuring within the for loop.

Comment: Use the `for...of` syntax:  `for (let fruit of fruits) { console.log(fruit); }`.

Comment: There isn't really any structure to `fruits[i]`, so there's nothing to destructure. I think you're misunderstanding what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want to keep the classic `for` loop:

```js
const fruits = [`apple`, `banana`, `orange`];

for (let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    const { [i]: res } = fruits;
    console.log(res); // apple banana orange
}
```

As a shorter syntax, [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) works with iterable objects (like arrays).

You can use it like this:

```js
const fruits = [`apple`, `banana`, `orange`];

for (const fruit of fruits) {
    console.log(fruit); // apple banana orange
}
```

To go further, you can even use destructuring in a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop (e.g: to retrieve the string lengths):

```js
const fruits = [`apple`, `banana`, `orange`];

for (const { length } of fruits) {
    console.log(length); // 5 6 6
}
```